# How to write specific catch for three level exception with message

Tags: exception

I have an exception I need to write a catch statement for that will catch only this exception.

The exception is:

var exception = new Exception("", new Exception("", new Exception("Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UKC_Invoice_Organisation'")));

Anyone know how to write the catch?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the initial 'oh god why' response...

```
catch (Exception e)
{      
  if (e.getCause() != null && e.getCause().getCause() != null && e.getCause().getCause().getMessage().equals("Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UKC_Invoice_Organisation'")
  {
    //do special handling here
  } else
    throw e;
}
```

That said, reconsider why you have that type of exception format.  Consider extending Exception so you can write a catch (MyCustomException e) block instead.